# Integration in product spaces

Tags: integration

I am getting ready for a qualifier in analysis and the following problem is from a sample qualifier:

Let $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $\mu-$integrable function and let $h:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $\nu-$integrable function. Define $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y).$ Show that $f$ is $\mu\times\nu-$integrable and that

$$
\int_{X\times Y} f\,d(\mu\times\nu)=\left(\int_X g\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Y h\,d\nu\right).
$$

MY ATTEMPT: I wanted to use Tonelli's Theorem to demonstrate the integrability of $f$, but I know nothing about the $\sigma-$finiteness of either of the measures. Then once I had the integrability established, I was going to use Fubini's Theorem to show the desired result. But again, I can't do that without some knowledge of the completeness of $\nu$.

I am not sure where to start with this since I know so little about the original measures. Any hints?

UPDATE: I have included an answer below that I think works. I would appreciate any kind of feedback available!

Comment: If $g$ is $\mu$-integrable, show that $g$ vanises outside a $\sigma$-finite set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vanishes outside a $\sigma-$finite set". A measure space can be $\sigma-$finite if the entire space is covered by a countable number of finite measure sets from the $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: A $\sigma$-finite set is a measurable set that can be covered by a countable number of finite measure sets.

Comment: Thanks. I've never heard of $\sigma-$finiteness extended to measurable subsets like that. Makes sense though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $g$ is $\mu-$integrable over $X$, then as long as $g\ne 0$ a.e. we have that $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite. Indeed, since

$$
X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left\{x\in X\,:\,|g(x)|\ge\frac{1}{n}\right\}\cup\{x\in X\,:\,|g(x)|=0\}.
$$

and by Chebychev's Inequality, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have

$$
\mu\left\{x\in X\,:\,|g(x)|\ge\frac{1}{n}\right\}\le \,n\int_X|g|<\infty,
$$

then $X$ is expressible as a countable collection of sets of finite measure with respect to $\mu$, we conclude that $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite. Similarly, since $h$ is $\nu-$integrable over $Y$, then if $h\ne 0$ a.e. we have $\nu$ is $\sigma-$finite as well.

Now if one or both of either $g$ or $h$ is zero a.e., then $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)=0$ a.e. and

$$\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,d(\mu\times\nu)=0=\left(\int_Xg(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh(y)\,d\nu\right).
$$

If both $g$ and $h$ are not zero a.e. then both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma-$finite and we can use Tonelli's Theorem on the positive and negative parts of $g$ and $h$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)&=g(x)h(y)\\
&=(g^+(x)-g^-(x))(h^+(y)-h^-(y))\\
&=g^+(x)h^+(y)-g^+(x)h^-(y)-g^-(x)h^+(y)+g^-(x)h^-(y)
\end{align*}
$$
so that

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,d(\mu\times\nu)&=\int_{X\times Y}g^+(x)h^+(y)-g^+(x)h^-(y)-g^-(x)h^+(y)+g^-(x)h^-(y)\,d(mu\times\nu)\\
&=\int_{X\times Y}g^+(x)h^+(y)\,d(mu\times\nu)-\int_{X\times Y}g^+(x)h^-(y)\,d(mu\times\nu)\\
&\qquad-\int_{X\times Y}g^-(x)h^+(y)\,d(mu\times\nu)+\int_{X\times Y}g^-(x)h^-(y)\,d(mu\times\nu)\\
&=\left(\int_Xg^+(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)\,d\nu\right)-\left(\int_Xg^+(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&\qquad-\left(\int_Xg^-(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)\,d\nu\right)+\left(\int_Xg^-(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&=\left(\int_Xg^+(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)-\int_Yh^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&\qquad-\left(\int_Xg^-(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)\,d\nu+\int_Yh^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&=\left(\int_Xg^+(x)\,d\mu-\int_Xg^-(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)-\int_Yh^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&=\left(\int_Xg^+(x)-g^-(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh^+(y)-h^-(y)\,d\nu\right)\\
&=\left(\int_Xg(x)\,d\mu\right)\left(\int_Yh(y)\,d\nu\right).
\end{align*}
$$
In either case, we achieve our desired result.